# Wrap text with <span> element using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code on my page. There is no containing element, it's just in the `body`.

```
<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>24.30<br>
```

Using script, I want to wrap `24.30` in a `span` tag with a class so the result will look like this:

```
<b>SqFt per Carton: </b><span class="sqft_cart">24.30</span><br>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: put the html code properly
put it on a new line afer 4 spaces.
check meta

Comment: i had posted the html code but the code is not shown.

Comment: following is the code:<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>
24.30
<br>            i want it like the following:<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>
<span class="sqft_cart">24.30</span>
<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a containing element you can use `.nextSibling()` to get the text node for `24.30`. Then `.insertAdjacentHTML()` inserts the new `span` after deleting the old text node. Since I don't know what the rest of your page looks like, I'll assume there could be multiple `<b>` elements, but the code will work either way.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/6ArzV/

Script:

```js
var bs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'b' );

for( var index = 0; index < bs.length; index++ ) {

    if( bs[index].innerHTML.indexOf( 'SqFt per Carton:' ) > -1 ) {
        var text = bs[index].nextSibling,
            span = '<span class="sqft_cart">' + text.nodeValue + '</span>';
        text.parentNode.removeChild( text );
        bs[index].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', span);
    };

};
```

HTML:

```html
<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>24.30<br>
<b>Price per Carton: </b>193.00<br>
<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>12.90<br>
<b>Price per Carton: </b>147.00<br>
<b>SqFt per Carton: </b>14<br>
```

CSS:

```css
.sqft_cart {
    color: red;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is jQuery way to achieve what you asked for by iterating over all text nodes (i.e. text without any tag) in the document, and in case they come right after `<b>` tag replace them with `<span>` having proper class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").contents().filter(textNodeFilter).each(function(index) {
        var textNode = $(this);
        if (this.previousSibling && this.previousSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() === "b") {
            var value = textNode.text();
            var oSpan = $("<span>").html(value).addClass("sqft_cart");
            textNode.replaceWith(oSpan);
        }
    });
});

function textNodeFilter() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/Ez2YL/1/).

Comment: but there are many <b> tags in the page so it will replace for all right?

Comment: Yes it will replace all "pure text" that come right after `<b>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("b").parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType != 1;
}).wrap("<span class='sqft_cart'></span>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FW8Ct/4/

Answer (score 0):

you could get the value of SqFt per Carton: 24.30 by using

```
var takentext = $("class Or ID of SqFt per Carton").text();
$("class of span").text(takentext);
```